# using prismjs in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use prismjs in my angular app
This is what i got so far

```
app.directive('nagPrism', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            source: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            if(!scope.source) {
                transclude(function(clone) {
                    element.html(clone);
                    Prism.highlightElement(element.find("code")[0]);
                });
            } else {
                scope.$watch(function() {return scope.source;}, function(v) {
                    if(v) {
                        Prism.highlightElement(element.find("code")[0]);
                    }
                });
            }

        },
        template: "<code ng-bind='source'></code>"
    };

}]);
```

This will work if i got something like this

```
<!-- This works  -->
<pre nag-prism source="code" class="language-css"></pre>
```

but i would like to make it work for something like this also

```
<pre nag-prism class="language-css">
<code>body {
color: red; 
}
  {{code}}

</code>
</pre>
```

For convenience i've made a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/teSogo2u5rmqVfd0TJg7?p=preview)
Any tips ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vyCUphlT2tULf0Z9v1Vb?p=preview
should be enough to get you started

Comment: @dave `scope.source.length` throws an error since scope.source is undefined,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I understand, your target is to build directive that highlights code either given as a constant, dynamically by variable or mix of two above. If you are not attached to syntax from your post, here is solution.

Main problem is that before applying Prism highlight function, code template needs to be compiled in order to change {{variables}} to their values. In your solution highlight function is applied to raw template.

The idea is to change binding type from '=' to '@' and pass source code as an attribute in all cases.

Old binding:

```
scope: {
    source: '='
}
```

New binding:

```
scope: {
    source: '@'
}
```

Angular documentation:

> @ or @attr - bind a local scope property to the value of DOM
>   attribute. The result is always a string since DOM attributes are
>   strings. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is
>   assumed to be the same as the local name. Given and widget definition
>   of scope: { localName:'@myAttr' }, then widget scope property
>   localName will reflect the interpolated value of hello {{name}}. As
>   the name attribute changes so will the localName property on the
>   widget scope. The name is read from the parent scope (not component
>   scope).

Updated html sample (mind that old binding from first example also has changed!):

```
<!-- This works  -->
<pre nag-prism source="{{code}}" class="language-css"></pre>

<!-- Now this works either!  -->
<pre nag-prism source="body {
    color: red; 
}
{{code}}" class="language-css"></pre>
```

Full updated directive code:

```
app.directive('nagPrism', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            source: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('source', function(v) {
                if(v) {
                    Prism.highlightElement(element.find("code")[0]);
                }
            });
        },
        template: "<code ng-bind='source'></code>"
    };
}]);
```

You can find working solution here: [working sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/OA9zs0cVUiMEflyj3sjk?p=preview)

**edit: directive updated to meet target from comment below**

In order to properly display transcluded content, it must be manually compiled. It causes some changes in directive code (version below uses transcluded content if it is not empty and source is not defined):

```
app.directive('nagPrism', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          source: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transclude) {
            scope.$watch('source', function(v) {
              element.find("code").html(v);

              Prism.highlightElement(element.find("code")[0]);
            });

            transclude(function(clone) {
              if (clone.html() !== undefined) {
                element.find("code").html(clone.html());
                $compile(element.contents())(scope.$parent);
              }
            });
        },
        template: "<code></code>"
    };
}]);
```

Following sample adds code block binded to input to show that linking works: [improved sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/F77rcio6e4Cj5T0Pk2w3?p=preview)

Comment: the idea back then was to make it work on the transcluded content also, it wasn't necessary needed in the app but i was curios if there is a way of doing it

Comment: @ionutvmi I've edited my answer so it meets this target

Comment: Thank you for your time on this problem. Would you have a different approach if the content where to be received later ? http://plnkr.co/edit/YBweYW6fVpGMJ961VbGc?p=preview

Comment: @ionutvmi I don't think that transcluded html is the best tool in this case. The problem you are dealing with is that Prism modifies DOM out of angular control when highlighting syntax. This means that directive html is no longer bound to angular scope after highlighting. To keep displayed code up to date, you need to save somewhere its raw version and track appropriate models changes (as you did in your plnkr). As you still need to pass somehow used variables in order to follow their changes, I think that cleanest approach would be just passing the whole code as a source attribute.

Comment: Thanks @ionutvimi for the plnkr. I just got to the same issue. The double watch on source and replacement variables works for me as well now.

Answer (score 3):

You only need reload the Prism plugin after your controller has been executed.

```
app.controller('StartController', ['$scope', function($scope){

 console.log('hello');

 Prism.highlightAll(); // Only this that you need do!

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the $stateChangeSuccss event handler

```
app.run(function($rootScope $timeout){
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
  $timeout(function() {Prism.highlightAll()}, 0);
});
```